# iPhone is set up with one Apple ID, but my Apple Card is under a different Apple ID. How to consolidate them?

Tags: iphone, apple-id, keychain, contacts, apple-card

OK, here's my dilemma. I've been using one apple ID for over 10 years. It has my contacts, notes, passwords (in Keychain), etc. Then about 2 years ago, when I was buying a new macBook, I signed up for an Apple Card. Unfortunately I gave them a different email. So as the result, my Apple Card is under a different Apple ID now, and I can't use it on my iPhone without losing my Keychain, contacts, notes, etc. (Moreover, the way that Apple Card is set up, I can't use it at all without an Apple device.)

I was thinking that it's easy to consolidate two accounts into one, but it seems like it is not. (At least with Apple.)

So thus my question, what is the easiest way for me to use my Apple Card on my iPhone?

Comment: There is no way to merge Apple IDs, Apple is not flexible when it comes to Apple IDs. If I had the same problem I would close the Apple Card account, request that the Apple ID being used with the card be deleted a couple of months after the card has been closed, and then apply for an Apple Card under my original Apple ID.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you simply cannot combine or merge two Apple IDs into one. This includes moving over services like Apple Pay, Apple Card, Music, Games, etc.

See this [Apple Insider](https://appleinsider.com/inside/icloud/tips/you-cant-combine-two-apple-ids----but-heres-what-you-can-do) article for more.

They offer a workaround, but it is cludgy at best.   You may have to close your Apple Pay account and new account under your correct ID. Is this ideal?  No, but it will solve the problem permanently

Comment: Wow. I'm upvoting it not because I like the answer. That's backwards. Btw, close a credit card account and then re-opening will affect your credit score.

Comment: Did you ask Apple about moving the card over to the other ID?  What did they tell you?  This is not relevant?  https://support.apple.com/en-us/102512 .  Now, it may not let you change it because the other ID already exists, I don't know.

Comment: @MarcWilson that support page is absolutely useless. The "call or chat with an Apple Card Specialist" link took me to a page with a phone number. And no other options. I called and got to the Goldman Sachs automated line, where you need to say what you want. Struggled with a dumb AI for about 10 minutes and then gave up....

Comment: @c00000fd - That’s because your Apple ID and Apple Pay are two different things. Your Apple ID is almost an immutable account where there ate  only minor changes that can be (i.e. your contact or payment info). Your Apple Pay account is just like a credit card account where you can close down (example: lost/stolen card) and re-open it with a whole new number the only entity that could be changed is the Apple ID associated with it think of it like your credit card must have your Social Security number always tied to it even if you change names.

Comment: That's what I was wondering.  Is it actually the **AppleID** that matters, or is it just the email address?  I don't have an AppleCard, never wanted one, so can't say.

Comment: The Apple ID is what matters.  Everything done under the ID is linked to it even if you change all the contact info.   I’m sure Apple will say it’s for security, but Apple IDs can be hijacked so…..